# Table layout query

Tags: html, flask

I have a card where I've presenting recipe info

In this card I have a table with html below.  The table has 2 columns, a section name and the amount of ingredients.  There's a 1 section to many amount of ingredients

```html
<table class='table table-hover text-sm'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Section name 1</td>
    <td>Amount Pretty 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Section name 1</td>
    <td>Amount Pretty 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Section name 2</td>
    <td>Amount Pretty 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The server code is

```
{% for res in results2 %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{res["SectionName"]}}</td> 
    <td>{{res["AmountPretty"]}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

What I'm looking to do is not repeat the section name ie. group the AmountPretty by section like in the style below.

```
Section 1
    ...amount pretty
    ...amount pretty
Section 2
    ...amount pretty
    ...
```

Is it possible to use tables to do this?  Or is there a better html construct to get this layout?

In the snippet I need to remove the second Section Name 1

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. This is not a flask question so I created you a snippet with just HTML. Please elaborate on your needs

Comment: I've updated the snippet to try and show

Comment: Why not have an empty variable then a test in the loop (pseudo code, I do not know Jinja): `if (head != res["SectionName"]) { head = res["SectionName"]; render a cell with res["SectionName"] }`

Comment: You should never use tables for layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that what you may actually prefer to use is a **nested list**, as in the example below:

```
<ul>
  <li>Section 1</li>
  <ul>
    <li>...amount pretty</li>
    <li>...amount pretty</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Section 2</li>
  <ul>
    <li>...amount pretty</li>
    <li>...amount pretty</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: How can I build that in flask?   I can see how I can loop through the data for li for amount but not sure about the section.   The Section and Amount is in the same list (from sql).